# How to write a script to write root shell in file.log?

Tags: bash, script

I use loger to write in file.log,but I can't execute the script.sh.I do it with bash script.sh and ./script.sh but I receive message 
bash: ./script.sh: Permission denied

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to edit the file, then you probably don't have permission to execute it. [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) is the command to set permissions on files in unix operating systems. `+x` is the flag to allow permission to execute.

The script needs to be executable before you can run it.

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

If you get a permission denied running that command, then you may need to elevate your permissions first:

```
sudo chmod +x script.sh
```

Now you should be able to run it again:

```
./script.sh
```

Comment: Not to worry! Good answer, +1.